# Can I send messages to an SNS topic in a different region using the SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I was wondering, is it possible to send messages to an SNS topic that is in a different region? Asking because can't find any leads through my research.

Basically I want to be able to send messages from the EU region to an SNS topic that has its region set to us-east-1 and that SNS will then publish the message to its subscribers

Comment: Send how? Using AWS console, boto3, aws CLI? What did you try?

Comment: AmazonSNS library for Java. There is a publish function of the client

Comment: Just set your java sdk to the given region.

Comment: So let's say I was in the EU region. Would I be able to publish to message to an SNS client set to the us-east-1?

Comment: Yes. I think @ErmiyaEskandary will be able to explain that in a moment:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to send messages to an SNS topic that is in a different region?

Yes, of course.

When you’re using the SDK, just set the region to `us-east-1`.

Nothing is stopping you from sending messages to an SNS topic in another region.

You can send messages to an SNS topic from anywhere on the internet as long as you call the correct regional endpoint for the topic (which is determined by the region you set in the SDK).

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. My question wasn't about subscribing to another SNS. I was wondering more if it was doable to be able to publish a message to an SNS in a different region. I would be calling a publish method through an SNS client (Java)

Comment: Ah okay haha, I’ll update answer - yes it is

Comment: Is the answer (marked as correct) correct ? This is what I found in the documentation "You can publish messages only to topics and endpoints in the same AWS Region." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-publishing.html Please clarify ?

Comment: @Rasika Yes it is - that sentence means that the topics and endpoints *both* need to be in the same region; it does not mention sending messages to another region. Try it out and you can verify :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you for the reply. The statement in the doc is confusing. Will try it out. Thanks again.

Comment: So you have to maintain a client in every region if you want to publish to multiple ones? Isn't there a simpler way that doesn't require keeping so many open clients?

Comment: @DidierA. Yes correct, it shouldn't be too much overhead? It’s not an ‘open’ client per se. Do you have any specific worries? The only 'simpler' way would be to provide the region in every API request but 90% of users will be using a specific region or at most, 1/2 regions where 2 clients should be normal.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the region on each call to publish using the SNS client's PublishRequest ? I would rather do that then juggle multiple injected singleton clients. I also would have expected the client to do that, since the topic ARN contains the region in it already.

Comment: No unfortunately - it'll throw an error at least on .NET if the ARN region does not match the region of the client (which either you explicitly specify or is inferred from your config.